# How to get Parent Product Id from Child Id in Magento 2 api

Tags: c#, api, magento, postman, magento2

I want to get the parent product id from the child product id in Magento 2.
Is there any API that can give this information? I see solutions in Php.
But I am using c# as a backend language. And wants to fetch this information via API.

Any input will be much appreciated.

Thanks & Regards